# Simplify: $\frac{\sin(3x-y)-\sin(3y-x)}{\cos(2x)+\cos(2y)} $

Tags: trigonometry

Simplify the following expression: $$\frac{\sin(3x-y)-\sin(3y-x)}{\cos(2x)+\cos(2y)} $$

I used the formula: $$\sin(\alpha)-\sin(\beta)=2*\cos...$$ and got to: $$\frac{\sin(2x-2y)}{\cos(x-y)} $$

If I put it on Wolframalpha, the alternate form is: $$2\sin(x-y)$$

What is the procedure, to fully simplify this expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\sin(2x-2y)=\sin(2(x-y))=2\sin(x-y)\cos(x-y)$, so $$\frac{\sin(2x-2y)}{\cos(x-y)}=\frac{2\sin(x-y)\cos(x-y)}{\cos(x-y)}=2\sin(x-y)$$

Of course with the exception of when $\cos(x-y)=0$.

Answer (score 3):

After getting $$ \frac{\sin(2x-2y)}{\cos(x-y)} $$

Which is $$ \frac{\sin \color{green}{2(x-y)}}{\cos(x-y)} $$

Using *Double Angle Formula*,

$$ sin(\color{green}{2\theta})= 2\cdot \cos(\theta) \sin(\theta) $$

We get our expression as,

$$ \frac{2\cdot \sin(x-y) \cos(x-y)}{\cos(x-y)} $$

$$ \require{cancel} \frac{2\cdot \sin(x-y) \cancel{ \cos(x-y)}}{\cancel{\cos(x-y)}} $$

And we are left with $$ 2\sin(x-y) $$